# Save and get details of Model class using userdefault

Tags: swift, mvvm, alamofire, objectmapper

I have one model object User and inside that another model object is Picture.

```
 "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "abc.k@gmail.com",
     "user_profile_photo": {
                "id": 997,
                "user_id": 1,
                "photo_url": "https://newproduction.s3.amazonaws.com/profile_image/RkUJAczv5nWpUyFTgyTgMLChR.jpeg",
                           }   
         }
```

I have two model class for this one is **User** and another is **Picture** inside user.
I am saving model user in userdefault as below

```
    //Get Response
    loginResponseObj = Mapper<LoginResponse>().map(JSONObject:(response.result.value))

   //Save user Details
   let userData = loginResponseObj.user!
        let data  = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: userData)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey:"user")
```

and when i am trying to get data from userdefaults, am getting **User** Model but inside details are nil.

Get Userdetails from userdefault Code is below

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user") as? Data
            else
        {
            return UserModel()

        }
        return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UserModel)!
```

This return `**<ABC.User: 0x7f84f740c440>**`

But when i am trying to get **Picture** from **User** it return nil

In **User** Model

```
 class User:NSObject,Mappable,NSCoding{

 var email: String?
 var picture: Picture?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
    }
    func initWithCoder(aDecoder:NSCoder) -> UserModel
    {
        self.email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String

        return self
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")
    }
```

}
In **Picture** Model

```
class Picture:Mappable,NSCoding{

    var id: String?
    var photoURL: String?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
            self.photoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "photoURL") as? String
        }
        func initWithCoder(aDecoder:NSCoder) -> Picture
        {
            self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
            self.photoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "photoURL") as? String

            return self
        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")


 }
```

}
**Note: I am using MVVM Pattern and Object Mapper**

So, How can i get the whole details of user including photo_url (User.Picture.photo_url) ?

Comment: How do you convert User to data, use NSCoding? Does your picture model conform to NSCoding ?

Comment: User model does but Picture Model Doesn't

Comment: And user model does? Make sure that your picture model also conform to NSCoding and it should be fine.

Comment: see my updated question
now i am able to get User.email using UserDefaults
But when i am trying to get Picture it returns nil

Comment: See the answer below

Comment: yes, I tried this also
But app got crashed after adding this

Comment: Crash:
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x60000029eaf0 of class 'Funcxnal.Picture' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Funcxnal.Picture replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
2018-04-23 15:13:50.089157+0530 Funcxnal[5008:178464] Unrecognized selector -[Funcxnal.Picture replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169576/discussion-between-neelam-pursnani-and-sandeep).

Answer (score 0):

In **User** Model

```
class User:NSObject,Mappable,NSCoding{

 var email: String?
 var picture: Picture?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
        self.picture = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "picture") as? Picture
    }
    func initWithCoder(aDecoder:NSCoder) -> UserModel
    {
        self.email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
        self.picture = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "picture") as? Picture
        return self
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")
        aCoder.encode(picture, forKey: "picture")
    }
}
```

In **Picture** Model

```
class Picture: NSObject,Mappable,NSCoding {

var id: String?
var photoURL: String?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
    self.photoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "photoURL") as? String
}
func initWithCoder(aDecoder:NSCoder) -> Picture
{
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
    self.photoURL = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "photoURL") as? String

    return self
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encode(photoURL, forKey: "photoURL")
}
```

Get Details From User Defaults

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user") as? Data
            else
        {
            return User()

        }
        return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? User)!
```

above code will return **User** Model
Using this model access its variables

```
print(user.email)
print(user.picture.photoURL)
```